# Figure is not being saved in plotly-dash out of a function. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a function that takes a matplotlib plot and turns it into a plotly plot using tls.matplotlib_to_pyplot. In the end I named it plotly_fig. Now I'm trying to add sliders to a dash webapp. But when I compile it, I get an error saying plotly_fig is not defined.
The following is some sample code that recreates the error.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import matrix_power
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.tools as tls
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
app = dash.Dash()
#begin with the knobs
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(
       id = 'graph',
       figure = plotly_fig),

   html.Label('Config L'), ## this is the knob for the length
   dcc.Slider(
       id = 'l',
       min = 5,
       max = 10,
       marks = {i: 'Label ={}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(5,10)},
       value = L,
   ),

   html.Label('Config n'), ##knob for the n-gon
   dcc.Slider(
       id = 'n',
       min = 0,
       max = 10,
       marks = {i: 'Label ={}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1,10)},
       value = n,
   ),

   html.Label('Config N'),  ##knob for the number of n-gons outside initial
   dcc.Slider(
       id = 'N',
       min = 0,
       max = 10,
       marks = {i: 'Label ={}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1,10)},
       value = N,
   ),

   html.Label('Config r'),  ##knob for r only works on integers for now
   dcc.Slider(
       id = 'r',
       min = 0,
       max = 2,
       marks = {i: 'Label ={}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in    range(1,2)},
       value = r,
   ),

   html.Label('Config d'), ##knoc for the depth of the dip
   dcc.Slider(
       id = 'd',
       min = 0,
       max = 2,
       marks = {i: 'Label ={}'.format(i) if i == 1 else str(i) for i in range(1,2)},
       value = d,
)
],
style = {'columnCount': 1})
@app.callback(
   dash.dependencies.Output('graph', 'figure'),
   [dash.dependencies.Input('l', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('n', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('N', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('r', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('d', 'value')])

def output(L,n,N,r,d):
    x = np.linspace(np.pi, L*n*N*r*d*np.pi, 1000)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(x, sinx)
    plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
    return{plotly_fig}
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `plotly_fig` is not even declared when you are trying to use it in the Graph's `figure` field. It is just declared locally in the callback.

It is not required to set the `figure` property of the Graph explicitly, It will be automatically mapped during the callback, so you can directly do it like this,

```
#your code here

app = dash.Dash()
#begin with the knobs
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(
       id = 'graph'),  # ==> here you can remove the figure as it will be automatically set during the callback.

    #your code here
],

style = {'columnCount': 1})

@app.callback(
   dash.dependencies.Output('graph', 'figure'), #here figure represents the field
   [dash.dependencies.Input('l', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('n', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('N', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('r', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('d', 'value')])

def output(L,n,N,r,d):
    #your code here
    plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
    return{plotly_fig}

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

In the above snippet case, the `value` property of the Slider is the input of the app and the output of the app is the `figure` property of the Graph. Whenever the value of the Slider changes, Dash calls the callback function `output` with the new input values. The function filters the dataframe with this new value, constructs a figure object, and returns it to the Dash application.

Meanwhile, if you want a default value to be set even before the callback function is called you can declare `plotly_fig` as a global variable like this,

```
#your code here
plotly_fig = None # declare the default figure here

app = dash.Dash()
#begin with the knobs
app.layout = html.Div([
   dcc.Graph(
       id = 'graph', figure = plotly_fig),

    #your code here
],

style = {'columnCount': 1})

@app.callback(
   dash.dependencies.Output('graph', 'figure'),
   [dash.dependencies.Input('l', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('n', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('N', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('r', 'value'),
   dash.dependencies.Input('d', 'value')])

def output(L,n,N,r,d):
    #your code here
    plotly_fig = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig)
    return{plotly_fig}

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)
```

For more information refer the official documentation page which has a similar example,

https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2